# How to build a dart server in a single file and run it on the Ubuntu server? (`dart compile exe` give an error)

Tags: linux, dart, dart-server

My host is Ubuntu 20.04(x86_64) and my PC is Windows 10 Home (64-bit operating system, x64-based processor).
I want to build a dart server to a single file.
So, I used this command

```
dart compile exe dart_server/bin/dart_server.dart -o dart_server-linux-x64
```

to build the `dart_server-linux-x64` file and move it to the host.
and run this file by

```
./dart_server-linux-x64
```

Then I got the error:

```
-bash: ./dart_server-linux-x64: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

How to solve that?
I tried uploading the folder project(dart_server). Then run this dart server from this folder and it works successfully.
But I want to use a single file, not the whole folder project. How to fix that?

Comment: I guess you compiled the binary on another OS platform than the target. That is not supported. If you want to run the binary on Linux, it must be compiled on Linux.

Comment: Is there any way to compile with cross-platform?

Comment: No, there are no way to cross-compile Dart code to a native executable that can be executed on all platforms. There are also, currently, not support for compiling a native executable for another platform than the one the compiler runs at. You can check the issue https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28617 about that.

Comment: If you have Dart installed on your server, you can compile your program as `kernel` target which basically just bundles everything together into a single binary file. The binary cannot be executed directly but can be executed with the same Dart version but for different OS: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#kernel

Comment: What is the exact OS and architecture of the server?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) with kernel version 5.4.0-122-generic, and architecture x86_64 (64-bit).

Comment: What is the OS and architecture of the other machine?

Comment: My com uses the Windows 10 Home (64-bit operating system, x64-based processor).

Comment: Ok, yeah, that won't work.  Your question made it seem like both machines were running Linux.  Perhaps you can use the Linux Dart SDK to compile in WSL.

Comment: I added the detail in the post. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28617#issuecomment-1043560689).

We can build dart project into `.exe` file by using git action.

I have the `dart_server` and `dart_share`(using in flutter and dart_server projects) projects.

This is my the directory structure

```
root
     - .github
          - workflows
               - github-actions-demo.yml
               
     - dart_server
          - bin
               - dart_server.dart
          - pubspec.yaml

     - dart_share
          - pubspec.yaml
```

The `github-actions-demo.yml` is

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI Building native server

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macOS-latest]
        include:
          - os: ubuntu-latest
            output-name: server-linux
          - os: macOS-latest
            output-name: server-mac
          - os: windows-latest
            output-name: server-windows.exe
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: dart-lang/setup-dart@v1.3
      - name: Install dependencies for share project
        working-directory: ./share_dart
        run: dart pub get
      - name: Install dependencies for server project
        working-directory: ./server
        run: dart pub get
      - run: mkdir build
      - name: Install Dependencies for share project
        working-directory: ./share_dart
        run: dart pub get
      - name: Install Dependencies for server project
        working-directory: ./server
        run: dart pub get
      - run: dart compile exe ./server/bin/server.dart -v -o build/${{ matrix.output-name }}
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: native-executables
          path: build
```